# "Welcome" Email for New Google Group Members

Tags: google-groups

How can I set up an automated welcome email to be sent to all new members joining a Google group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. The best you can do is to [create a welcome message](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2465458?hl=en).

Comment: Has anything changed since 2013?